# Android Market - Application not visible

Tags: android, android-ndk

**Hello everybody**

I am here to ask your kind support on this matter since it is ruining about 1 year of development for just an application visibility problem.

We have developed a game called Fantasy Racing which has been published few days ago on the Android Market under the racing category but the game is not visible at all.

This problem already occurred on another simple game we have developed in the past but we didn't focus much on it since the efforts were minimal, now, this application is our biggest effort so far hence, I need to resolve this issue.

The application is:

- Visible in the list of the applications of the publisher profile
- Found if you search by name

The application is not visibile in:

- Category Games in general
- Category Games/Racing, there are about 20 pages of racing game and I can find games such as "happy s. valentine" and "Angry birds" but not my game, even at the last position
- We checked almost all the sections and the game is not listed anywhere.

The android market support responds with an automatic bot.

We are desperate.

I think it could be depending on the android manifest file configuration.

I would really thank you if you could help me to identify any problem on it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="false" >
</supports-screens>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="ADWHIRL_KEY"
        android:value="adda8faafddd4e08be96b61a98ad0e3b" />

    <activity
        android:name="org.teamnovasoft.racegame.gameactivity.IntroSplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.teamnovasoft.racegame.gameactivity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdViewOverlayActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

EDIT: The game uses 2 native libraries using Android NDK. I don't know if it is relevant or not :(

Comment: This will change after a couple of days / maybe a week.

Answer (score 3):

You should decrease API level in application manifest file.

My situation was:

```
1. I compiled my apk with API level 10
2. I browsed Google Play from Google Account that have only device that supports API level 6 applications.
```

So I had situation when my application wasn't visible from my account, because it was filtered.

Answer (score 2):

There might be 2 possibilities:

- take a couple of days, for my app, around 1week.
- Google Play just do not show all the apps in the market. You may need promote it by increasing downloads to get is shown in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.

The reason was only a matter of time before the indexing system of Google has published the application.

I was habit to a faster response from the market in the old days when the number of daily application releases was much lower. Now, the market is overwhelmed by applications and this require a longer time to process newcomers.

If it does happen to you, it depends on time.

Another possible explanation would be the manifest configuration which could filter your device from displaying the product but this was not my case.

It is definitively non related to the promoting of the app.